# How do I install a 32-bit proprietary deb on a 64-bit system without causing dependency problems?

Tags: apt, 64-bit, software-installation, proprietary, multiarch

I know Guitar pro doesn't support 64 bit, but i did get it to work with this command

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i GuitarPro6-rev9063.deb
[sudo] password for jeggy: 
Selecting previously unselected package guitarpro6:i386.
(Reading database ... 285729 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking guitarpro6:i386 (from GuitarPro6-rev9063.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of guitarpro6:i386:
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on gksu.
dpkg: error processing guitarpro6:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 guitarpro6:i386
```

And even after i get that error the program perfectly works fine and updating and adding PPA's to the system works great, but when I'm trying to install some other software i get this error:

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ sudo apt-get install elinks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elinks : Depends: libfsplib0 (>= 0.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: liblua50 (>= 5.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: liblualib50 (>= 5.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libtre5 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: elinks-data (= 0.12~pre5-7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 guitarpro6:i386 : Depends: gksu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And whenever i write "apt-get -f install" i get this

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for jeggy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dconf-gsettings-backend:i386 python-levenshtein python-indicate libav-tools libstartup-notification0:i386
  libxmuu1:i386 libavfilter-extra-2 libbabl-0.0-0 libgegl-0.0-0 libgconf2-4:i386 python-vobject libgtk-3-0:i386
  libpam-cap:i386 python-utidylib libdconf0:i386 python-iniparse python-xmpp libpam-gnome-keyring:i386
  libxcb-util0:i386 python-farstream
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  guitarpro6:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 84,0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 286979 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing guitarpro6:i386 ...
dpkg: warning: while removing guitarpro6:i386, directory '/opt/GuitarPro6/updater' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing guitarpro6:i386, directory '/opt/GuitarPro6/Data/Soundbanks' not empty so not removed.
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
```

And now Guitar Pro is deleted. 
How can i install Guitar Pro and still be able to install other software afterwards?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> ### Warning:
>
> The *GuitarPro* deb is **dangerously packaged!**
>
> - On a 64-bit system, if you `apt-get -f install` after trying to install it, `apt-get` will want to **remove** the following **system critical packages**, which can ruin your Ubuntu installation!
>
>   ```
>   The following packages will be REMOVED:
>   gksu guitarpro6:i386 libgksu2-0 libpam-gnome-keyring sudo ubuntu-desktop
>   ubuntu-minimal update-manager update-notifier xauth xinit xorg
>   ```
> - *sudo*? *update-manager*?? *X!* What are the developers thinking?!  It also makes `apt-get` think a bunch of i386 packages are installed when none have been. [Here's the full gory pastebin.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1043224/)

---

### Safely Install GuitarPro without `apt-get` wanting to remove it

- I believe the above behavior comes from the deb's dumb dependency on `gksu:i386` (which is the graphical root elevation package)
- Unfortunately, the only safe way to install this *and* not have to deal with `apt-get`'s whining is to *manually* install it and its dependencies. Here's how:

### How to manually examine and safely install a binary i386 deb with its dependencies

- First, remove the current half-installed packaged with `sudo dpkg --remove guitarpro:i386`
- Now, change to the directory where your deb file is stored. For easy typing let's create a short symlink - my deb called `gp6-full-linux-demo-r11100.deb`, yours may differ:

  - `ln -s gp6-full-linux-demo-r11100.deb gp6.deb`

#### 1. Examine the deb's architecture and dependencies

First, we examine the deb's dependencies without installing it.

- `dpkg-deb -I gp6.deb` shows us:

  ```
   new debian package, version 2.0.
  size 172147458 bytes: control archive= 75020 bytes.
   375 bytes,    10 lines      control

  335109 bytes,  2770 lines      md5sums

  Package: GuitarPro6
  Version: 6.1.3
  Section: non-free/audio
  Priority: optional
  Architecture: i386
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.1.3), libstdc++6, libasound2, libxml2, libxslt1.1, libportaudio0, libportaudio2, libglu1-mesa, gksu, libssl0.9.8
  Installed-Size: 222632
  Maintainer: Arobas Music 
  Description: http://www.guitar-pro.com
  Guitar Pro 6, Linux Version.
  ```
- So this is an i386 application, and all its dependencies are also going to be i386.
- The **first thing** to do is install the `ia32-libs` i386 compatibility package, if you haven't already:

  - `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
- Let's also copy and paste the package's dependencies in a text file, for later.

#### 2. "Extract" the deb into a tar archive and examine its contents

- Let's *extract* the deb to a tar archive now so we can examine its contents without having to install it:

  - `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile gp6.deb > gp6.tar`
- And open up the File Manager (Nautilus), and mount the `gp6.tar` as an archive by right-clicking and selecting *Open in Archive Mounter*; *after* that you'll see `gp6.tar` added to the bottom the left sidebar, with an eject icon next to it:

  [image]
- Go to the View Menu for File Manager, and change the Sidebar to the *Tree* view option instead of *Places*:

  [image]
- Now expand the `gp6.tar` tree in the sidebar by clicking on the triangles; repeat for each level until you can see *the folder structure* of the file:

  [image]
- From the structure, we see that the program's files go into two locations: `/opt` and `/usr/share`:

  - Anything that goes into `/opt` is self-contained and will not affect anything else on the system.
  - We see that `/usr/share` only contains icons/bitmaps, which are harmless.

#### 3. If it's safe, "install" the program by extracting the tar file

- Go back to the terminal, and make sure you are in the directory containing the downloaded deb/tar files. Then type:

  ```
  sudo tar -C / -xvf gp6.tar
  ```
- This will extract the program files in the appropriate locations, showing you the file names and progress. ([**Sample Output**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1053721/))

  - The `-C` switch tells `tar` to perform this operation relative to the root directory, not the current directory.

#### 4. Figure out which dependencies are missing with `ldd`, install them, and rock-and-roll!

- Open up the `/opt/GuitarPro6` folder in the File Manager:

  [image]

  - We see that the executable is called GuitarPro (with the diamond-"gears" icon), and also that a lot of `lib-xxxx` files are included in the folder.
  - This is normal for binary-only programs; they try to include the versions of the specific libraries they need, since those may not be available from the repositories of a specific distribution.
- Along with these included libraries and the `ia32-libs` package, most 32-bit dependencies should have been installed. Instead of blindly installing the dependencies we saw in the deb file info via `apt-get`--which can cause problems-- let's figure out if we're *actually* missing anything.

  - Go back to the terminal, and change to the GuitarPro directory with `cd /opt/GuitarPro6`

*Using `ldd`*

- Type `ldd GuitarPro | grep found`, and the output will be `libportaudio.so.2 => not found`

  - `ldd` prints the dependencies (shared libraries) of a program, and whether they exist or not on the system. [Here's what the full output of GuitarPro looks like.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1053740/)
  - To make life easier, we simply filter for the ones that do not exist via `grep found`.
- Here, only the *libportaudio2* library is missing. But the dependencies said *libportaudio**0**?* (see step 1.) Which is it??

  - Let's search for the available versions using `apt-cache search libportaudio` from the terminal.
  - That's tells us that *both* `libportaudio2` and `libportaudio0` packages are available. Let's install the *2* first, with

    ```
    sudo apt-get install libportaudio2:i386
    ```
  - The *:i386* part is **very important**, since our program is 32-bit. If `apt-get` asks to replace/remove `libportaudio2` and/or other files, that's OK, because some libraries cannot be installed simultaneously in both 32- and 64-bit versions.
- Let's double-check dependencies one final time: `ldd GuitarPro6 | grep found` gives us *nothing* (that's what we want!)

  - If you get the error `./GuitarPro: /opt/GuitarPro6/./libz.so.1: version ZLIB_1.2.3.3 not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2)` this means that Guitar Pro is [using a wrong version of libz](https://www.linux.com/home/128-desktops/494464), fix this by removing the libz.so.1 file from the GuitarPro6 directory:

    ```
    sudo rm libz.so.1
    ```

    Guitar Pro will fall back to the libz version of your system.
- Exit the terminal and go back to the `/opt/GuitarPro6` folder in the File Manager. Double-click GuitarPro and...

  [image]
- Clean-up the Download folder by deleting the tar file from the File Manager.

#### 5. The launcher shortcut has already been added

- Because the package already contained a `GuitarPro6.desktop` shortcut that was extracted to `/usr/share/applications`, there is no need to manually create one. It's sitting there in the Launcher:

  [image]

Comment: Yeah well everything went fine, except when the last time I used ldd GuitarPro6 | grep found
it gave me a response:

./GuitarPro: /opt/GuitarPro6/./libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.3.3' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2)

Comment: I tried to install this on another computer(12.10 64bit), and i ran into an other error, and this fixed it: http://bit.ly/X7nvJ5 . Just wanted to share it here, if anyone else ran into some problems

Comment: What an amazing answer. This worked perfectly on Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit. I wish I could upvote more than once... FYI, I also had to do `sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386` in addition to `libportaudio2:i386`

Comment: It works perfectly in 14.04

Answer (score 1):

I tried something out and got it to work!

1. I copied "/opt/GuitarPro6" somewhere.
2. I did `sudo apt-get -f install` to remove Guitar Pro.
3. I copied the folder back into `/opt/GuitarPro6` and replaced everything there.
4. I installed more packages as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-gsettings-backend python-levenshtein python-indicate libav-tools libstartup-notification0 libxmuu1 libavfilter-extra-2 libbabl-0.0-0 libgegl-0.0-0 libgconf2-4 python-vobject libgtk-3-0 libpam-cap python-utidylib libdconf0 python-iniparse python-xmpp libpam-gnome-keyring libxcb-util0 python-farstream
   ```
5. I downloaded this image [GuitarPro icon](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Guitar_Pro_icon.png) and saved it in `/opt/GuitarPro6/icon.png` so i could have an image to create my own `.desktop` file.
6. I created a `.desktop` file with `sudo gedit`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Name=Guitar Pro 6
   Comment=Guitar Pro 6
   Icon=/opt/GuitarPro6/icon.png
   Exec=sh /opt/GuitarPro6/gp-launcher.sh
   Terminal=false
   Categories=Audio
   ```

   I saved this file into `/usr/share/applications` with the name `GuitarPro6.desktop`.

Now everything works and I can find Guitar Pro in the dash.

Comment: That is a horrible solution.

Comment: What better solution is there? I've tried all the others have answered. do you know any better one? and this one actually works fine.

Comment: You've installed all the dependencies of Guitar Pro?

Comment: well now i did this `sudo apt-get install dconf-gsettings-backend python-levenshtein python-indicate libav-tools libstartup-notification0 libxmuu1 libavfilter-extra-2 libbabl-0.0-0 libgegl-0.0-0 libgconf2-4 python-vobject libgtk-3-0 libpam-cap python-utidylib libdconf0 python-iniparse python-xmpp libpam-gnome-keyring libxcb-util0 python-farstream` . and it works just as fine.

Comment: In the future, you should not run `sudo gedit`. You should use `gksu gedit` or `gksudo gedit` instead. Running graphical programs as `root` using plain `sudo`, when the application has per-user configuration files, can [mess up those programs for the non-`root` user](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).

Comment: Ah, so you hadn't tried all the suggested fixes before then. You should really either fix your answer to be correct, or better yet, choose my answer as the correct one since I told you to install the dependencies.

Comment: i did try your answer, but whenever i install the .deb file it breaks again and even if i have installed the dependencies manually

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/154490/58612) for how to manually examine and install a proprietary (non-open-source) deb file and its necessary dependencies, without causing apt-get problems or having to create shortcuts. Should work for any such 32-bit deb on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

I've also been struggling with this over the past few days.
I've found the best way is to use the Windows executable under wine. Seems a lot more solid.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, to stop `apt-get -f install` from removing software you need to add `--no-remove` to the command you run. This will immediately abort the apt-get run if something is to be removed and your software will not be removed.

However, what you are probably looking for is a way to have a system run normally, yet also have that software installed. What you will need to do is look at the output from when you forces the installation of the package with dpkg, and see what it is failing on, then install that dependency using

`apt-get install package-name`

In your case, it is gksu (specifically, gksu). Now you may find that when you attempt to install gksu that it has dependencies as well that need to be installed. Since you are forcing the 32-bit package install, you will need to manually install these dependencies using the same command above.

Answer (score 0):

I simply installed gp6 under LinuxMint 14 32-Bit, ran updater and fixed issues with zlib by copying zlib.so1.2.27 to /opt/GuitarPro, renaming it to zlib.so.1, installed gksu and its dependencies, ran the updater again for bringing all up to date. Afterwards i connected my 64-bit Linux to 3s-Bit Linux via fish://username@mymachineIP/opt in Dolphin and copied the whole GuitarPro6 dir to my home dir on 64-Bit Linux and from there to /opt. Works.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

Download from http://www6.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php?pg=download the .deb file but don't install it.

Download and install [getlibs](http://www.ginlemonblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/getlibs-all.deb)
Then:

```
sudo apt-get install libportaudio0
getlibs -l libportaudio.so.2
dpkg -i –force-all /path/to/GuitarPro6Demo2.deb
```

Finally, launch it with (ignore errors):

```
/opt/GuitarPro6/gp-launcher.sh
```

Comment: That didn't work any better than i did before :(