# Steam on Ubuntu 64bit 15.10?

Tags: 64-bit, steam, 15.10

I have downloaded the online installer from Steam's website. However, steam doesn't want to work after the installation process. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 64bit. How can I get steam to work?

#### Edit1:

I have tried the following command: sudo apt-get install steam
Steam still does not work.

#### Edit2:

More details as requested.
I have tried the following command in the terminal: `steam`

This is the output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit  
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically  
[2015-12-06 21:38:07] Startup - updater built Nov  9 2015 18:23:22  
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred  
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjDLb.jpg)

Comment: Are you using open source drivers for a Radeon or NVidia card? FWIW, Valve only officially supports Steam on the LTS Ubuntu.

Comment: can you [edit] your post and add the output of the command `steam`

Comment: @Neil It encounters an error. I have edited my post with the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run these commands in terminal :

32Bit

```
mv $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

64bit

```
mv $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

This solution may have solved steam errors like yours in other posts, e.g. this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617358/problem-starting-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit).
As it has not been marked as solved yet, please tell me if this works or not.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I had to use both of the commands however to make Steam work.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it directly from the Ubuntu Software Center app.

Some info on this page as well, though may be out of date.  But it has references to some resources that can help.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve

Comment: Ubuntu software centre doesn't have it. :(

Comment: Weird, now I see that - it shows up in the USC for me but if I click it then it's not found.

Try going to a terminal window and running

    sudo apt-get install steam

Comment: I have attempted this as well. Steam updated, but it still does not start.