# How to install Guitar Pro 6 on Kubuntu 15.10 64bit?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, kubuntu, 64-bit, multiarch

first I have followed this description:

[installing gp6 in saucy by hacking the .deb file](http://paoloambrosio.net/2013/11/16/installing-guitarpro6-on-ubuntu-1310-saucy-64bit.html)

I assume, that it is outdated, because it does not work properly. After rebuilding the package and trying to install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i gp6-manipulated.deb
```

gives the following

```
Entpacken von guitarpro6:i386 (6.1.9) ...
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von guitarpro6:i386:
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libasound2.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libc6 (>= 2.1.3).
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libglu1-mesa.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libportaudio0.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libportaudio2.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libssl0.9.8.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libstdc++6.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libxml2.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von libxslt1.1.
 guitarpro6:i386 hängt ab von zlib1g.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes guitarpro6:i386 (--install):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
Trigger für mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 guitarpro6:i386
techmod@buildr:~/Downloads$
```

Trying to install them as i386-version with for instance

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i368
```

always gives back, that the package couldn't be found (doesn't matter which one)

Trying to solve the issue by using synaptic ends up in synaptic telling, that I have one broken package and that I should repair it. As a result of repairing, synaptic deletes the faulty package and installs a lot of stuff. Unfortunately the package does not install afterwards giving the same output as above.

Then I tried this solution:

[installing gp6 using ldd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149951/how-do-i-install-a-32-bit-proprietary-deb-on-a-64-bit-system-without-causing-dep)

But using the command

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i gp6-manipulated.deb
```

ended up with the same problems that i had before.

As i tried the next recommendation (installation of ia32-libs) I found out, that they were replaced by *lib32z1* and *lib32ncurses5*. Installation with

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5
```

returned the following:

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Probieren Sie »apt-get -f install«, um dies zu korrigieren:
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 guitarpro6:i386 : Hängt ab von: libasound2:i386
 Hängt ab von: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) soll aber nicht installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: libglu1-mesa:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: libportaudio0:i386 ist aber nicht installierbar
 Hängt ab von: libportaudio2:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: libssl0.9.8:i386 ist aber nicht installierbar
 Hängt ab von: libstdc++6:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: libxml2:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: libxslt1.1:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: zlib1g:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
 lib32ncurses5 : Hängt ab von: lib32tinfo5 5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
 Hängt ab von: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) soll aber nicht installiert werden
 lib32z1 : Hängt ab von: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) soll aber nicht installiert werden

E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie **»apt-get -f install«** ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
techmod@buildr:~$
```

If i would try to fix this problem with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

it would break the Installation.

After following the steps 2 and 3, I am stuck a little, because changing the directory to /opt/GuitarPro6 and using

```
ldd GuitarPro | grep found
```

will return nothing, but doesn start the program. It just shows up in the Panel and then dissapears right away.

During earlier attempts the command showed up a lot of dependencies according to libc and so on.

Any help is welcome here. if it is useful,

```
ls
```

gives the following:

```
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$ ls
Data                                         libprofiler.so
gp6-linux.checklist                          libQtCore.so.4
GPBankInstaller                              libQtDBus.so.4
GPConverter                                  libQtGui.so.4
GPInstaller                                  libQtNetwork.so.4
GPUpdater                                    libQtOpenGL.so.4
GuitarPro                                    libQtSvg.so.4
launcher.sh                                  libQtWebKit.so.4
libboost_date_time-gcc43-mt-1_39.so.1.39.0   libQtXmlPatterns.so.4
libboost_filesystem-gcc43-mt-1_39.so.1.39.0  libQtXml.so.4
libboost_regex-gcc43-mt-1_39.so.1.39.0       libregister.so
libboost_system-gcc43-mt-1_39.so.1.39.0      libRSEAudioCore.so
libboost_thread-gcc43-mt-1_39.so.1.39.0      libRSECore.so
libchunk.so                                  libthread.so
libexception.so                              libtimer.so
libfactory.so                                libvariant.so
libfilesystem.so                             libWavFile.so
libGPCore.so                                 libxml.so
libmemory.so                                 libZip.so
libmmap.so                                   Presets
libobject.so                                                        SoundbanksVolumeChangesSettings.ini
libOverLoud.so                               updater
libphonon.so.4                               xsl
libPickupModeling.so
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$
```

EDIT: i have investigated my install a little and I found, that I had to install the packages via synaptic. Regardless of breaking the install as mentioned above.

I made a .tar-archive with

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile gp6-manipulated.deb > gp6-man.tar
```

and installed it with

```
sudo tar -C / -xvf gp6-man.tar
```

When i change to /opt/GuitarPro6 and use

```
ldd GuitarPro | grep found
```

I get the following:

```
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$ ldd GuitarPro | grep found
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libpulse.so.0 => not found
    libpulse-simple.so.0 => not found
    libXrender.so.1 => not found
    libvorbis.so.0 => not found
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libpng12.so.0 => not found
    libfreetype.so.6 => not found
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libSM.so.6 => not found
    libICE.so.6 => not found
    libXrender.so.1 => not found
    libfontconfig.so.1 => not found
    libfreetype.so.6 => not found
    libXrender.so.1 => not found
    libfontconfig.so.1 => not found
    libXrender.so.1 => not found
    libfontconfig.so.1 => not found
    libfreetype.so.6 => not found
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$ sudo tar -C / -xvf gp6.tar
```

EDIT2: i managed to install all the dependencies required and got it running and I was able to register my copy. Unfortunately the process stopped and threw this:

```
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$ ./GuitarPro
ALSA lib conf.c:3325:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared   library     libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default

RtMidiOut::initialize: error creating ALSA sequencer client object.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rtmidi::RtError'
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$
```

Comment: You need to manually install those 32-bit dependencies. Try searching for them on packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, but it worked halfways only...see the edit inside my post

Comment: Looks like it needs Alsa installed, but I don't know if installing it will conflict with Pulse Audio.

Comment: I got it up and running but without the ability to pull updates. When I have solved this I will post an answer. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As i said, heree is the answer to my question above:

**STEP 1**

First I checked the architecture of my system with:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

Bash is giving the following:

```
amd64
```

The next step is to determine, which other architectures might be supported:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

This will print:

```
i386
```

Now just add the new architecture with:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update
```

**STEP 2**

This step is accordingly to the steps 2+3 and 4 given in this answer:

[How do I install a 32-bit proprietary deb on a 64-bit system without causing dependency problems?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149951/how-do-i-install-a-32-bit-proprietary-deb-on-a-64-bit-system-without-causing-dep)

Unpack your GuitarPro 6 *.deb-archive and make it a *.tar-archive with:

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile whatever_your_gp6_package_is_called.deb > whatever.tar
```

and unpack it to it´s proper location automatically by typing

```
sudo tar -C / -xvf whatever.tar
```

Open the bash and change to:

```
/opt/GuitarPro6/
```

If you type:

```
ldd GuitarPro | grep found
```

bash will list all unmet dependencies which are:

- gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_i386
- libasound2_1.0.29-0ubuntu1_i386
- libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4_i386
- libfontconfig1_2.11.1-0ubuntu6_i386
- libfreetype6_2.5.2-4ubuntu2_i386
- libglib2.0-0_2.46.1-1_i386
- libglu1-mesa_9.0.0-2_i386
- libice6_1.0.9-1_i386
- libportaudio0_18.1-7.1_i386
- libportaudio2_19+svn20140130-1build1_i386
- libpulse0_6.0-0ubuntu13_i386
- libpulse0_6.0-0ubuntu13_i386
- libsm6_1.2.2-1_i386
- libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu4_i386
- libstdc++6_5.2.1-22ubuntu2_i386
- libstdc++6_5.2.1-22ubuntu2_i386
- libxml2_2.9.2+zdfsg1-4_i386
- libxrender1_0.9.9-0ubuntu1_i386
- libxslt1.1_1.1.28-2build2_i386
- zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4_i386

Now head over to packages.ubuntu.com, search for them and download them.
They should be installable by Qapt. Every dependency not listed here is going to be resolved automatically. There is only one exception:

- libc6, libstdc++ and libssl won´t be installed by Qapt. Just make them a *.tar-archives and install them as mentioned above.

Check your dependencies again with:

```
ldd GuitarPro | grep found
```

and there shouldn´t be any dependencies left.

**STEP 3**

Unfortunately GP6 still refuses to start. The splash will show up and crash instantly. This is due to the ALSA drivers on your system. Bash gives you this:

```
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$ ./GuitarPro
ALSA lib conf.c:3325:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default

RtMidiOut::initialize: error creating ALSA sequencer client object.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rtmidi::RtError'
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
techmod@buildr:/opt/GuitarPro6$
```

You can solve this easily by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
```

**STEP 4**

Now your GP6 will start, but it wonj´t be able to pull updates, because the updater and the installer cannot become root (kdesudo and gksu got deleted while performing the above installation).

Simply type:

```
sudo apt-get install kdesudo gksu
```

Now you are ready to rock! Here is some proof, that it worked.

[image: updating]
[image: installing]

Answer (score 1):

Since the software provided on Guitar Pro's website is a 32-bit `.deb` file, I created a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/aviggiano/guitar-pro-6/) to install [all necessary packages](https://github.com/aviggiano/guitar-pro-6) on whatever architecture you have:

```
docker pull aviggiano/guitar-pro-6
xhost +local:root
docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -it aviggiano/guitar-pro-6
```

References:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarPro/comments/4vqlpc/installing_guitarpro6_on_64_bit_ubuntu_1604_and/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/etetoolkit/4SrZk5fRtCM

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.

Comment: @raaj After I built the docker image, that error vanished. 1. Build 2. Use on of the 7 scripts to run GP6