# How to install Guitar Pro 6 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, 19.04, 32-bit, deb

Guitar Pro 6 is not maintained anymore but it is still provided as a 32 bits deb package for native Ubuntu/Debian install.

I could not install the deb package 32 bits on 64 bits Linux OS because of package dependencies. There are some old answers to this problem and none worked for me on Ubuntu Studio 19.04 ([How to install Guitar Pro 6 on Kubuntu 15.10 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693586/how-to-install-guitar-pro-6-on-kubuntu-15-10-64bit/946337#946337)).

When i try the docker solution:

```
docker pull aviggiano/guitar-pro-6
xhost +local:root
docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v $HOME/.Xauthority:$HOME/.Xauthority --net=host -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -it aviggiano/guitar-pro-6 /opt/GuitarPro6/launcher.sh
```

The GUI Starts now but no sound and Guitar Pro 6 does not appear in pulseaudio volume control.

Comment: consider to switch to TuxGuitar http://www.tuxguitar.com.ar/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux) (it has v. 7 in the list)

Comment: Kindly separate the question and the answer and then post the answer below as an actual answer.

Comment: As @Parto requested, I moved your answer posted as a part of the question to a [separate answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179267/250300). Feel free to repost it using your account. See also https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17983/what-do-we-do-with-this-question-that-is-really-an-answer/ and https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. I put more details on my question.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, you should not accept the current answer. You should also edit your question or add a comment about why it isn’t sufficient.

Comment: @Melebius Indeed I'm still searching an answer to install the native version of Guitar Pro 6.

Comment: I think what would be very useful, is to package the debian package as an AppImage thus including all dependencies and distribution independant.

Comment: I asked the maintainer of the docker repository. He said that the command line was wrong and the good file to start was /opt/GuitarPro6/launcher.sh. But now i have another problem ... "Cannot connect to the X server".

Comment: And are you using X or Wayland?

Comment: adding -v $HOME/.Xauthority:$HOME/.Xauthority --net=host allows to start the gui but now i have no sound ... The docker seems overkill for average users.

Answer (score 3):

*This answer was originally posted as a [part of the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1178855/1).*

I finally installed the win32 exe of Guitar Pro 6 with wine and it runs smoothly. It took me 1 minute...

Download Guitar Pro 6 then:

```
$ sudo apt install wine
$ wine gp6-full-win-r11686.exe
```

To install soundbanks, go to Help / Updates / click the "repair" button. It will download all packages needed and install it on your Guitar Pro 6 wine installation.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and want to confirm this solution still works as of September 2021. Very easy